# the cost decreased but the time was practically the same, why?

Tags: postgresql, performance, index, postgresql-9.3

#### Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE schema.mylogoperation (
  id_mylogoperation serial,
  data DATE,
  myschema VARCHAR(255),
  column_var_2 VARCHAR(255),
  user VARCHAR(255),
  action TEXT,
  column_var_1 TEXT,
  log_old VARCHAR,
  log_new VARCHAR
  constraint pk_mylogoperation primary key (id_mylogoperation)
) 
WITH (oids = false);
```

- 12 million rows

#### I tried to explain analyze:

```
explain analyze
SELECT
    column_var_1,
    column_var_2
    column_var_3,
    user,
    action,
    data,
    log_old,
    log_new
FROM schema.mylogoperation
WHERE
    myschema = 'schema'
AND column_var_2 IN ('mydata1', 'mydata2', 'mydata3')
AND log_old <> log_new
AND column_var_1 LIKE 'mydata%';

indexes ( pk_mylogoperation only)
QUERY PLAN
Seq Scan on myschema  (cost=0.00..713948.14rows=660 width=222) (actual time=380.308..4467.364 rows=48 loops=1)
  Filter: (((log_old)::text <> (log_new)::text) AND (column_var_1 ~~ 'mydata%'::text) AND ((schema)::text = 'schema'::text) AND ((column_var_2)::text = ANY ('{mydata1,mydata2,mydata3}'::text[])))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 12525296
Total runtime: 4467.425 ms
```

#### Then I tried to create a some index for better performance:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_mylogoperation_1    ON schema.mylogoperation (myschema, column_var_2);

reindex table schema.mylogoperation;
analyze schema.mylogoperation;

pk_mylogoperation + idx_mylogoperation_1
QUERY PLAN
Index Scan using idx_mylogoperation_qry1 on mylogoperation  (cost=0.56..589836.84 rows=658 width=223) (actual time=331.679..4997.507 rows=48 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (((myschema)::text = 'schema'::text) AND ((column_var_2)::text = ANY ('{mydata1,mydata2,mydata3}'::text[])))
  Filter: (((log_old)::text <> (log_new)::text) AND (column_var_1 ~~ 'mydata%'::text))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 7441986
Total runtime: 4997.580 ms
```

#### Then I tried again to create a some index for better performance:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_mylogoperation_2 ON schema.mylogoperation USING gin (column_var_1 gin_trgm_ops);

reindex table schema.mylogoperation;
analyze schema.mylogoperation;

pk_mylogoperation + idx_mylogoperation_1 + idx_mylogoperation_2
QUERY PLAN
Bitmap Heap Scan on idx_mylogoperation_var_1  (cost=1398.58..2765.08 rows=663 width=222) (actual time=5303.481..5303.906 rows=48 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (column_var_1 ~~ 'mydata%'::text)
  Filter: (((log_old)::text <> (log_new)::text) AND ((myschema)::text = 'schema'::text) AND ((column_var_2)::text = ANY ('{mydata1,mydata2,mydata3}'::text[])))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 248
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_mylogoperation_var_1  (cost=0.00..1398.41 rows=1215 width=0) (actual time=5303.203..5303.203 rows=296 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (column_var_1 ~~ 'mydata%'::text)
Total runtime: 5303.950 ms
```

#### The question

- the cost decreased but the time was practically the same, why?

*Notes*:

- I do not want to make changes to the select operation, just in the database structure.
- This test was performed on a server that is in use. But creating these indices was efficient? Or rather do not use them.
- I am using Postgres 9.3.22 on Linux 64-bit Red Hat.

Comment: The costs that query planners use to pick plans are only *estimates*, based on expected operation complexity, row counts, and value distribution in indexes (judged by basic statistics that are kept). Relative cost of CPU and IO operations will also very between machines in relatively unpredictable ways. *So it is not always the case that the highest cost value plan is actually the slowest.* I'll leave it for those with more specific postgres experience to suggest why it might not be able to make better use of the index(es) you have created, and how you might help it do a better job.

Comment: Actual performance is hugely dependent on how "hot" the cache is, which is hard to model in the cost estimates.  Is your performance fully reproducible?  If you run each of the three queries repeatedly back to back, what kind of performance do you get on successive runs?

Comment: "I am using Postgres 9.3.22 on Linux 64-bit Red Hat"  That is quite old.  There have been a lot of performance improvement since then.